# Google Map advice

Tags: json, google-maps

I've never used Google Maps for web sites.

I would like to know if it's possible to use it without having coordinates in my database? I  only have the name of a city.

I want to get city names from json response, and show all events locations on google map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes. and there are lots of examples here at SO and on Google.